# Command line calculator that keeps fractional values

Tags: command-line, calculator, bc

I just found a good command line calculator program called **bc** and was satisfied with it until I discovered it rounds off fractional values, thus causing loss in precision.

According to its `man` page:

> All numbers are represented
>   internally in decimal and
>          all computation is done in decimal.  (This  version  truncates 
>   results
>          from divide and multiply operations.)

Could you please suggest an equivalent of **bc** for Ubuntu Maverick? I need to make advanced command line calculations with variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the length of the fractional part with `scale=n`.

The command `echo 'scale=20;752/447' | bc` yields:

```
1.68232662192393736017
```

Note that even if the number fits within the scale, additional zero's might be appended:

```
scale=20
1/2
.50000000000000000000
```

Unfortunately, there is always a rounding issue:

```
scale=50
1/3*3
.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Comment: could the scale value be set as global or I should always set it explicitly whet start bc?

Comment: @sergionni: You should always pass the `scale` variable to `bc`. The only environment variable that *might* be useful is `BC_ENV_ARGS`. This variable puts some arguments to `bc`, you could create a file with standard variables or settings, and set `BC_ENV_ARGS=/path/to/variables/file`. Please read the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/bc.1.html).

Comment: I tend to start bc via `bc -ql`. `-q` hides the copyright banner (which generally proves distracting) and `-l` loads the math library and automatically sets the scale to 20. (See `man bc`.)

Answer (score 11):

`calc` (I believe from package `apcalc`) does the same as `bc`, but does not round. It displays similarly to `bc`, but unlike `bc`, it understands scientific notation. Example:

```
> calc
C-style arbitrary precision calculator (version 2.12.3.3)
Calc is open software. For license details type:  help copyright
[Type "exit" to exit, or "help" for help.]

; a=234
; b=a/7
; b
    ~33.42857142857142857143
; c=b/1e20
; c
    ~0.00000000000000000033
; c*1e10
    ~0.00000000334285714286
;
```

Compare with `bc`:

```
> bc -l
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
a=234
b=a/7
b
33.42857142857142857142
c=b/10^20
c
.00000000000000000033
c*1e10
(standard_in) 6: syntax error
c*10^10
.00000000330000000000
```

A little search turns up lots of results, not all of which are relevant, but I am sure that a few trials will get you exactly what you want (wcalc, for instance):

```
aptitude search calc
i   apcalc                               - Arbitrary precision calculator (original name: calc)
i A apcalc-common                        - Arbitrary precision calculator (common files)
p   apcalc-dev                           - Library for arbitrary precision arithmetic
p   bandwidthcalc                        - file transfer time calculator written in GTK+
p   calcoo                               - Scientific calculator (GTK+)
p   calcurse                             - text-based calendar and todo manager
p   concalc                              - console calculator
p   extcalc                              - multifunctional scientific graphic calculator
p   gcalcli                              - Google Calendar Command Line Interface
i   gcalctool                            - GNOME desktop calculator
p   ipcalc                               - parameter calculator for IPv4 addresses
p   ipv6calc                             - small utility for manipulating IPv6 addresses
p   kcalc                                - calculator for KDE 4
p   keurocalc                            - universal currency converter and calculator - binary package
p   keurocalc-data                       - universal currency converter and calculator - data package
p   lcalc                                - a program for calculating with L-functions
p   libcolor-calc-perl                   - Perl module for simple calculations with RGB colors
p   libdate-calc-perl                    - Perl library for accessing dates
p   libdate-pcalc-perl                   - Perl module for Gregorian calendar date calculations
p   libmath-basecalc-perl                - Convert numbers between various bases
p   libmath-calc-units-perl              - Human-readable unit-aware calculator
p   libmath-calculus-differentiate-perl  - Algebraic Differentiation Engine
p   libmath-calculus-expression-perl     - Algebraic Calculus Tools Expression Class
p   libmath-calculus-newtonraphson-perl  - Algebraic Newton Raphson Implementation
p   libticalcs-dev                       - Texas Instruments calculator communication library [development files]
p   libticalcs2-7                        - Texas Instruments calculator communication library
p   libwww-google-calculator-perl        - Perl interface for Google calculator
p   octave-physicalconstants             - provide physical constants values in Octave
i   openoffice.org-calc                  - office productivity suite -- spreadsheet
v   openoffice.org2-calc                 -
p   python-ipcalc                        - perform IP subnet calculations
v   python2.6-ipcalc                     -
p   r-cran-epicalc                       - GNU R Epidemiological calculator
p   rpncalc                              - RPN calculator trying to emulate an HP28S
p   science-numericalcomputation         - Debian Science Numerical Computation packages
p   sipcalc                              - Advanced console-based ip subnet calculator
p   subnetcalc                           - IPv4/IPv6 Subnet Calculator
p   sugar-calculate-activity             - calculate activity for the Sugar graphical shell
p   tapecalc                             - a full-screen tape editor that lets the user edit a calculation
p   transcalc                            - microwave and RF transmission line calculator
p   wcalc                                - A flexible command-line scientific calculator
p   wmcalclock                           - A dock.app which simply tells time and date
p   xsmc-calc                            - Smith Chart calculator for X
```

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using Python as a command-line calculator:

```
$ python
>>> from math import *
>>> help(sin)
    sin(x)

    Return the sine of x (measured in radians).
```

Also I would recommend IPython or IDLE. Both hugely improve usability of the standard shell.

**Update**: use python3 to avoid truncation surprises:

```
$ python2.7

>>> 10/3
3

$ python3

>>> 10/3
3.3333333333333335
```

Comment: Best calculator ever. You could do anything.

Comment: That truncates calculations too.

Comment: It won't truncate anything if you divide e.g. like this: 2.0 / 100. Of course 2 / 100 would equal to 0, because it's an integer division.

Answer (score 6):

You lost precision in this sense: if set precision to 10 decimal digits, divisions are truncated to 10 decimal digits, and this is a coherent choice.

If you look for an exact calculator, you need a symbolic system as `maxima`.

By the way, `bc` supports variables.

Comment: yes, I know it support variables,that's I'm asking for analog

Answer (score 5):

"genius" is the most advanced calculator out there, with both command-line and GUI options available.  Check the manual for details, and see http://www.jirka.org/genius.html .

To install, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install genius gnome-genius
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good one:

[spigot](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/spigot/) -- a command-line exact real calculator

Answer (score 1):

If you have `octave` installed you can use it at the command line as:

```
octave --silent --eval 752/447
```

To shorten the writing you can add the following as alias in `.bashrc`

```
alias ose='octave --silent --eval'
```

and then call it as `ose 752/447`. The alias/shortcut is arbitrary but you need to restart the terminal to make it effective.

You can install `octave` using:

```
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Of course, with `octave` you can use all the advanced functions available in it too.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a simple one:

https://github.com/jb55/ratio-cli

```
$ ratio <<< '14/15 * 3'
14/5
```

Comment: does it support variables?

Comment: it's dead simple right now, just basic expressions. maybe one day?

Comment: the OP specified that it needs t handle variables