# How do I solve mathematical expressions in a file from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, calculator

I have created a file that contains arithmetic expressions, one per line. How can I evaluate the expressions and display the results, from the command line?

The file looks like this:

```
1 + 2
6 * 4
97 % 12
43215 / 43 * 100
```

The goal is to output each result, in order, also one per line. I recall there is a way to do this that only requires one command, and that command used might start with `w`, but I can't remember how.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I hate to say "google it", but this question could have been answered with a quick google of "bash math". See [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: This was closed as "not about Ubuntu." I don't see anything in [the help page about our scope](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) or [meta] to support that. It seems at least as on-topic as most other simple terminal-based tasks, and we have [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/378661) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/q/35608), which are different but related. The close reason strongly suggests it *wasn't* closed "as homework," which [I don't think we do anyway](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2224), plus I think my edit fixes that and the quality problems. The answer is for Ubuntu and well-received.

Comment: Though clearly related, does [Any command line calculator for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378661/any-command-line-calculator-for-ubuntu) really answer this? Both the question there and all its answers are entirely about interactive use. The task asked about here--running a single command to noninteractively simplify arithmetic expressions from a file--is not covered there.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `bc` as calculator, and send your file to it as input:

```
$ cat maths.txt
1 + 2
6 * 4
97 % 12
43215 / 43 * 100

$ bc < maths.txt
3
24
1
100500
```